# How do I say that I'm in the process of movement and am going to do something?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, tense

*First, I would like to apologize if my question has been answered somewhere, but I'm overwhelmed with the search results repeatedly telling me about the using of **be going to do** to express the future.*

My question is how to tell that I'm moving right now in order to do something, e.g. to open the door. Specifically, can I use the word **go** or some of its forms for that purpose?

My first thought was to say **I'm going to open the door**. However, I have been taught the construction **to be going to do something** means **to do something in near future**.

What if I say **I'm going to the door to open it?** Is it still about the future? (=**I'm going to go to the door to open it?**)

*Thank you for all your help.*

UPD: [Link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDaYn.png)

Comment: _I'm opening the door._

Comment: I am not opening the door. I go to open the door. Here is the picture. :) http://i.imgur.com/LHFVgMs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to open the door.

could be used in both scenarios (depending on implied meaning in context), but as is it would be better to use:

> I'm going to open the door.

for the *intent* to open it at some future time, and

> I'm going to the door to open it.

for the action of movement.

But it is context dependent. If you were already at the door, then the issue of movement does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to say "I'm walking to the door to open it," "I'm going to open the door makes sense." If you want to say "I'm about to open the door," then "I'm going to open the door" also makes sense. A native speaker would be able to figure out which sense you meant from the context.

"I'm going to the door to open it" also makes sense as a way to say "I'm walking to the door to open it."

Basically, any of the constructions you used make sense!

Comment: Oh, so it is ambiguous then. Is there any difference between "I'm going to open the door" and "I'm going to the door to open it"? I mean, maybe the first one is perceived more like "about intentions", and the second is more like about "being walking".

Comment: By the way, is it better just to say "walking" instead "going"?

Comment: Going sounds more natural.

Comment: And the about in tensions versus, being walking is a perfect way of describing the difference in sense.